# Looping error, too many records added

Tags: for-loop, ms-access, while-loop, vba

Ive been trying to write  Access VBA code to automate the addition of replicates for germination tests.

Basically I have a form where I enter the total number of Reps (NoofReps) and the number of seeds per rep (RepSize) (e.g. 50 seeds). For each  record added I want it to automatically add a record for each rep and automatically calc the Rep Number (i.e if i have 4 reps then it should add 4 records, numbered 1-4 reps) as well as the RepSize (e.g 50).

I have been trying out various loops based on information from this forum and other but am still getting errors with the number of records that it generates. I have tried both the "Do while" and "Do Until" but get the same result below either way.

Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong?...If i want 2 reps then it adds 2, If i want 3 then its 246, and if i want 4 it adds >30,000!!!

For the purposes of trying to fix the code I have started to type the number of reps manually into the code in the iNoofReps so that I know the error is in the code and not from the form.

```
Private Sub CmdAddReps3_Click()
Dim iRepNo As Integer   ' stores the current value in the series

'Open the table
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rstGReps = db.OpenRecordset("tblGReplicates")

' Initialise the variables
iRepNo = 1
iNoofReps = 3   'iNoofReps = Me.txtNoofReps

' Add the records using a loop
    rstGReps.movefirst

Do 'Until rstGReps("RepNo") = (iNoofReps + 1) ' always want to include at least 1 repNo

rstGReps.AddNew
rstGReps("GTestID") = Me.GTestID
rstGReps("RepNo") = iRepNo
rstGReps("NoofSeed") = Me.txtNoOfSeeds

' Calculate the next RepNo value in the loop
iRepNo = iRepNo + 1
rstGReps.Update
rstGReps.moveNext

Loop Until rstGReps("RepNo") = (iNoofReps) + 1 ' so that the loop includes the final repNo.

MsgBox "Finished Looping"
rstGReps.Close

Set rstGReps = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're moving next here: `rstGReps.moveNext`, and then you're comparing `rstGReps("RepNo") = (iNoofReps) + 1` after moving next, thus being on an empty record, thus always equating to false.

`Loop Until iRepNo = (iNoofReps) + 1` should fix it, then you're no longer referring to the recordset, which has already been set to the next record by the time you're referring to it.

You could also fix it by just eliminating this line:

`rstGReps.moveNext`

Since `rstGReps.AddNew` already moves the recordset to a new blank record, moving it forward after adding the record doesn't make much sense. If you remove it, you might want to remove the `+ 1` in `Loop Until rstGReps("RepNo") = (iNoofReps) + 1`